# How may I use Firebug to view attributes of jQuery-retrieved objects at a breakpoint?

Tags: jquery, attributes, firebug

For instance, I've hit a break point on a line of code where I'm setting the height of one div equal to the height of another:

```
$("#box_left").height = $("#box_right").height;
```

How do I view the value of 'height'?  All firebug ever shows me is 'function()'.   :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this to print the height in the console:

```
$("#box_left").height();
```

Also, to set it like you want, do this:

```
$("#box_left").height($("#box_right").height());
```

[`.height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) without arguments returns the height, giving it a value sets the height.

Comment: @Anton - If this solved your problem, please click the check-mark beside this answer indicating that, same for future questions...it helps the next person with your problem that finds this quickly identify the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

you can add the expression to a watch window
the watch window shows the value when the variables are in scope